# window.open() call not hitting controller first time

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Please help me with this ridiculous problem.
I am passing a URL from my js form by using window.open() function that will hit a controller method and also some path variable is included..
that is,

```
myUrl = "controller/"+pathVar1+"/"+pathVar2+"/controllerMethod?AUTH_TOKEN=" + getAuthTokenId() +"&";

window.open(myUrl,true);
```

getAuthTokenId() is written in my "global.js" file And in the controller I have written the method as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class ControllerName{

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{pathVar1}/{pathVar2}/controllerMethod", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody void ControllerMethodDefinition(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("pathVar1") String pathVar1,@PathVariable("pathVar2") String pathVar2){
        /***/
    }

}
```

Now My problem is when first time the js is executing my call from js is not hitting the controller but next time onwards the controller is hit every time.

Comment: Try investigating the problem by using Browser plugin tools to identify whether the browser is actually sending the request the first time. I usually use a firefox plugin called Tampterdata that shows request and response traffic between the browser and server. If the request is going to server, see what url it is going to.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, the best way to investigate is that:

1) Put `alert('Before open ' + myUrl);` and `alert('After open ' + myUrl);` before and after your window.open() command, to make sure it was executed.

2) `System.out.println("Controller hit. Pathvar 1 = " + pathVar1 + "; Pathvar 2 = " + pathVar2);` in your controller to make sure that it is really hit.

My guess is that somehow at first time your URL is not properly initialized, so that the command won't run. But whatever the reason, it should be clear after you perform 2 above tests.

Comment: Long
Thank you very much for suggesting me. alert('Before open ' + myUrl);and alert('After open ' + myUrl); both are working as properly and both time they are giving same URL.. And in the mean time the controller method is hit. but when I am clicking 'OK' in After Open Alert then the samething is happening.. So partially my purpose has been served that is the controller is doing as expected but after clicking ok on 2nd alert i have no control on the program..But from 2nd time onwards it's working properly..

Comment: @user1978891: as your reply, I think it's a javascript problem only. Could you post it as a jsfiddler page (http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here is the link.. You can see.. sceureDomailUrl is "secure/" .. it's defined in global.js...http://jsfiddle.net/Gvafq/

Comment: @Ajijul: your code works fine for me(tested on Chrome & Firefox). Are you sure that the javascript is already loaded when you call testReportShow()?

Comment: I mean that do you put the function call in jQuery(document).ready()... or window.onload? It may fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion.. Finally I got the answer when I took a look in my HTML form..  Thank you @Long for redirecting my thoughts to my js page..

Comment: @Ajijul: nice to hear that you solve the problem. Would you mind sharing the reason? It may benefit others coming here :).

Comment: @Long :-  Sure. In my html form I have declared the input type as "submit" and onclick I called the js method. But the input type should be "button". Otherwise "submit" action + onclick action both will try to perform their job. so after onclick has triggered the submit action is taking place. thats why the problem was occuring..